# How to display only submenu of a menu in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, class, menu

I have several class `menu-item`. When I mouse over on `menu-item` the sub-menu is always showing.
But as we can see, `sub-menu` is only on `id=menu-item-2292`.

```
<ul class="menu" id="menu-menu-principal">
   <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-2289"><a href="/about">À propos</a></li>
   <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-2292">
      <a href="/photos">Photos</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-2296"><a href="/portrait">Portrait</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

How can I do that show the `sub-menu` only if `menu-item` has a `sub-menu`?

Comment: Is it always going to be the same menu item that has a submenu or can that change. If so how are you generating the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.menu-item').hover(function(){
  var submenu = $(this).find('.sub-menu');
  if (submenu.length != 0) {
    submenu.show();
  }
}, function(){
  $(this).find('.sub-menu').hide();
});
```

Comment: YOU ARE A GENIUS ! It's perfect. Thank you Shree

Comment: Oh no, sorry, it doesn't work. When I mouse out `menu-item` the submenu disappear...

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [`has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) selector to reduce the selected set to `li` containing `ul`

```
$(".menu-item").has('ul.sub-menu').hover(function() {
    $('.sub-menu', this).show();
}, function() {
    $('.sub-menu', this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Yep, good. But now, the problem is : When I tried to mouse over the `sub-menu`, this one hide... Why ? Check out my code :            `$(".menu-item").has('ul.sub-menu').hover( 
          function () { $('.sub-menu').show(); },
          function () { $('.sub-menu').hide();}
        );`

Comment: please post your css styles.
you should also restrict `show()` and `hide()` to elements in `this`.
i updated my post